# DD WRT drops connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a TP-Link wireless router (model WR841N v3) with DD WRT on it (don't ask why it was here like this).

There are 3-5 devices connected to it (wireless) and sometimes one or more of them drop the connection. When this happens I can access the DD WRT GUI (currently on IP 10.0.1.1) but can't connect to the internet. If I change the Local IP in the 'Basic settings' of DD WRT and apply the new settings then I'll be able to connect to the internet again but the DD WRT GUI will be inaccesible (timeout). In the former case (no internet, accessible DD WRT GUI) ipconfig /all says that the Wireless LAN adapter's default gateway is 10.0.1.1, same as the Local IP set up in DD WRT. In the latter case it shows something different then the Local IP. I have very limited (literally no) network knowledge.

There were no changes in DD WRT's default settings (as far as I know) only the WiFI was configured (default settings, security setup, etc). Do you guys have any guess why is this happening?

Comment: This is common if you are running an image from the router database. (You shouldn't use these) get them from the downloads section, the ones in the searchable database are plauged with bugs/issues. I would start there, grab a recent image and upgrade the firmware. Let me know if you run into issues.